# ADFS 2.0 and Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have 2 servers (Windows 2008) each representing a different forest forest. On one of the servers I installed SharePoint 2010 server and I created a web application on the second server I set up ADFS 2.0. The objective is to ensure that users of my domain where adfs accesses the application thanks to SSO authentication. I followed this tutorial: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10452.sharepoint-2010-how-to-install-and-configure-adfs-2-0-on-windows-server-2008-r2-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx.ADFS 2.0 in my identify is https:// heb/_trust infact my problem is that when I try to access my application I get an error message DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.by cons when I change the URL of my application in https:// he I get to the login page but after authentication DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN it tells me when I arrive at the URL https://heb/ _trust . why I have a message "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN when I use the URL https: // heb to access my application?

Comment: Sorry the good url is :
 http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10452.sharepoint-2010-how-to-install-and-configure-adfs-2-0-on-windows-server-2008-r2-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: Please edit and make the point of your question clearer.